# Google Firebase Auth in Unity: How to read error codes

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

When using the Google Firebase Authentication plugin in Unity, how do you read error codes of faulted requests?

For example, within this code:

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
        if(task.IsFaulted){
            Debug.Log("ERROR ENCOUNTERED: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        if(task.IsCompleted){
            // Success!
        }
    });
```

You can see that if an error occurs I can log the exception out, which prints the following:

> ERROR ENCOUNTERED: System.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
>
> Firebase.FirebaseException: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

That's very human-readable, but not very elegant to put into a switch statement. Is there any way for me to cast the task.Exception to be a FirebaseException so I can grab the error code? And is there a list of these error codes somewhere? I can find the documentation for the FirebaseException, but the error codes aren't there. Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

So while I am still hoping for an answer, I've come to think that Google expects developers to use blanket error statements based on the context of the request. For example, when failing to sign in with an email and password (as in the above code), we should use the common statement of "Email or password is incorrect." The problem with that is that I can't let the user know the difference between them providing the incorrect details versus them entering an email which doesn't have an account associated with it at all.

Comment: Here is a solution! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036083/google-firebase-how-to-catch-specific-auth-exception-errors-unity/53036084#53036084

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've solved this by now but I've just come across the exact same problem and I'll share my solution:

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), System.AggregateException is a representation of one or more errors that may occur during the task execution.

Therefore, you'll need to loop through the InnerException(s) presented by the AggregateException, and look for the suspected FirebaseException:

**Retrieving the FirebaseException:**

```
AggregateException ex = task.Exception as AggregateException;
if (ex != null) {
  Firebase.FirebaseException fbEx = null;
  foreach (Exception e in ex.InnerExceptions) {
    fbEx = e as Firebase.FirebaseException;
    if (fbEx != null)
      break;
  }

  if (fbEx != null) {
    Debug.LogError("Encountered a FirebaseException:" + fbEx.Message);
  }
}
```

**Getting the Error Code:**

Wish I could help here but I haven't found anything - these aren't documented within the official API, AFIK. The only reference states: ["If the error code is 0, the error is with the Task itself, and not the API. See the exception message for more detail."](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-exception?authuser=3&hl=vi#errorcode)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same dilemma trying to find out which error code I get from Firebase and display appropriate message for the user.

The correct way to read the Firebase Exception is with this function I created:

```
bool CheckError(AggregateException exception, int firebaseExceptionCode)
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseException fbEx = null;
        foreach (Exception e in exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
        fbEx = e as Firebase.FirebaseException;
        if (fbEx != null)
            break;
    }

    if (fbEx != null)
    {
        if (fbEx.ErrorCode == firebaseExceptionCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("test@gmail.com", "password").ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            if(CheckError(task.Exception, (int)Firebase.Auth.AuthError.EmailAlreadyInUse))
            {
                // do whatever you want in this case
                Debug.LogError("Email already in use");
            }
            Debug.LogError("UpdateEmailAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
        }
    }
```

Here is some more code samples from firebase:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/auth/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Auth/UIHandler.cs

I got the answer from this thread:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/96

I hope this will help someone. All the best!

Comment: Your code really looks a lot like the code in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962002/4916627). How exactly is your answer different/better?

Comment: I tried implementing the other answer from here and it didn't work. The difference is this line: exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions. Also you can have use cases for the Auth exceptions, getting them from here: (int)Firebase.Auth.AuthError.*

Comment: replace `fbEx = e as Firebase.FirebaseException;` by `fbEx = e.GetBaseException() as FirebaseException;` then it works perfectly